# Can Michelin Star Amuse Bouche recipes be adapted to cater to dietary restrictions

Tags: vegan, restaurant-mimicry

Can Michelin Star Amuse Bouche recipes be adapted to cater to dietary restrictions, such as gluten-free or vegan options?

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ section from the link you provided answers your question for the most part. Although it only mentions vegetarian options, rather than vegan. But in short, the answer is yes. If you're after advice on how to adapt said recipes, or suggestions for ingredients, then that is a different question.

Comment: And the answer to Q5 specifically says that chefs make gluten free and dairy free.